# Solution of a differential equation having a singularity (not everywhere defined)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definition

Remind me about ordinary differential equations, whose solutions are not everywhere defined (have a singularity).

I want to remember the exact definition of a solution with singularity, which I studied in a university long time ago.

And please, an example.

Comment: There should be an answer. For example, in GR the solution is defined on the entire space except of black holes. It isn't an arbitrarily chosen part of space

Comment: You should review the Wiki for [Singular solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_solution)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> A solution $x(t)$ of the ODE is called maximal if it is defined on an
>   open interval and cannot be extended to any larger open interval.

From "Ordinary Differential Equation". Alexander Grigorian. University of Bielefeld. Lecture Notes, April - July 2008

So the things I search for are **maximal solutions**.

The question remains: What is the best generalization of this for PDE?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest example is the `finite time blow-up' ODE:

$$
y^\prime =y^2,\qquad y(0)=1
$$

This equation has the unique solution

$$
y(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}
$$ which is not defined when $t=1$.  So technically speaking, $y(t)$ isn't a solution to $y^\prime=y^2$ for all time - we have to choose an interval where the solution makes sense.  The rigorous approach would go as follows:

We say that $y(t)$ is a (classical) solution to the following ODE

$$
y^\prime=f(t,y),\qquad y(0)=y_0,\qquad a<t<b
$$ If

1. $y^\prime(t)$ *exists* for all $a<t<b$ (note this requires that $y(t)$ itself exists for all $a<t<b$)
2. $y^\prime(t)=f(t,y)$ for all $a<t<b$
3. $y(0)=y_0$

Any solution which fails to satisfy these conditions at some point could be called a `singular' solution.  The example $y^\prime=y^2$ violates the first condition: $y^\prime$ doesn't exist when $t=1$.  However, if we restrict the problem to read as follows:

$$
y^\prime=y^2,\qquad y(0)=1,\qquad 0\leq t<1
$$ Then $y(t)=(1-t)^{-1}$ is a classical solution.  Note that I have included the left endpoint assuming the appropriate definition of the derivative at $t=0$.

There is much more - I recommend picking up a book on ODE theory e.g. Hartman or Arnold.

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I also want an exact definition which makes this into a solution. (I don't see the reason why it is allowed to be undefined in one particular point.) Why empty function (the function having empty set as the domain) is not also a solution?

Comment: As far as I remember when I studied the empty function was not a solution. In your definition nothing prevents to consider empty function as a solution. I want a more exact definition

Comment: I don't have a good definition for the derivative of an empty function, so I think saying "$y^\prime$ exists" covers that.  I could be mistaken though.

Comment: What I remember exactly from my study in a university is that for a DE like this there was solution like $f(t)+C_1$ for $t<1$ and $f(t)+C_2$ for $t>1$. In the definition I search for the solution was not on an interval but on the union of two intervals with different independent constants $C_1$ and $C_2$

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comment below icurays1's answer, I think you're simply interested in solving differential equations on disconnected domains.

You might take some differential equation and try to find a solution on $\mathbb R\setminus D$, where $D$ is a discrete set of points. (This would rule out the empty function, as $D$, being discrete, cannot be all of $\mathbb R$.) For what it formally means to be a solution, see icurays1's answer: basically the appropriate derivatives must exist at all points of $\mathbb R\setminus D$ and the equation must be satisfied at each point of $\mathbb R\setminus D$.

For example, the functions $f:\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb R$ satisfying the equation $f'=0$ are precisely the functions which are equal to some constant $C_1$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and equal to some (possibly different) constant on $C_2$ on $(0,\infty)$. More generally, I think you might also be interested in the concept of a [locally constant function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_constant_function).

Comment: Your answer does not rule out $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ for $y^\prime =y^2$

Comment: @porton: that's right. It doesn't. Should it? Note that $f(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}+C_n$, where $C_n$ is a different constant for each interval of $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb N$, solves the equation $y'=y^2$.

Comment: See my above comment about general relativity